# How to narrow type in a switch statement

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have the following code

```
type Person = {
    race: string
}
type Animal = {
    species: string
}

export const adaptor = (
    input: Person | Animal,
    type: string
): string => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'person':
            return printRace(input); <-- Type error
        case 'animal':
            return printSpecies(input); <-- Type error
    }
};


function printRace(input: Person) {
    return input.name
}

function printSpecies(input: Animal) {
    return  input.species
}
```

Currently I get the error:

```
Argument of type 'Person | Animal' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type 'Animal' but required in type 'Person'.ts(2345)
```

in the first case (similar error for the other case).

How can I get `printRace` case to know that the input would never be type `Animal`?

Currently the only way I can achieve that is by casting it:

```
return printRace(input as Person);
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to include the `type` directly in the `Person` and `Animal` type. The benefit is that you won't need to include a `default` in your switch statement, as Typescript will know that you have provided a case all possible values of `input.type`

```
type Person = {
    type: 'person',
    race: string
}
type Animal = {
    type: 'animal',
    species: string
}

export const adaptor = (
    input: Person | Animal,
): string => {
    switch (input.type) {
        case 'person':
            return printRace(input);
        case 'animal':
            return printSpecies(input);
    }
};


function printRace(input: Person) {
    return input.race
}

function printSpecies(input: Animal) {
    return input.species
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlEgC4oBySJNcgGn0PgEMBjCMxYeAS1QHNcAX1zFoAQVTcAtkwA2mHAwKiy5JpJmy6SqIkgtuERBy68Bw3BAAeYZPGBQWaTlCYATJmGB2FACh28YACuwGRw1OgAPlAS0nL0AJQmPPyYAHyKhLoA7tzALAAWUL6BIQB0ogmZWYQsTIjQlAgoqOQkOjWMEMBB8OhgKcAASqwQJajBwAkA3B219Y3qcVrtnZ3w3b39gwDK+oaI45MzOsKCs7i4AGZBqCzA3GhQA7zDo0chYc1oVXhZGz0+lBSsAysw2EJLjc7g8ni9UMA9hADEYPqEYho5L8dACtsCJuU9MiDkIgA)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a different parameter for the type, you could just use `typeof` to determine the type:

```
export const adaptor = (
    input: string | number,
): string | number => {
    switch (typeof input) {
        case 'string':
            return printString(input);
        case 'number':
            return printNumber(input);
    }
};


function printString(input: string): string {
    return "Hello" + input
}

function printNumber(input: number): number {
    return  input + 100
}
```

For custom types the procedure is a little bit more inconvenient if you want to stay type safe:

```
type Person = {
    name: string
}
type Animal = {
    species: string
}

const adaptor = (
    input: Person | Animal,
): string => {
    if(isPerson(input)){
        return printPerson(input);
    } else if(isAnimal(input)){
        return printAnimal(input);
    } else {
        throw Error("Input is not of type Person or Animal");
    }
};

function printPerson(input: Person) {
    return input.name
}

function printAnimal(input: Animal) {
    return input.species
}

function isPerson(obj: any): obj is Person {
    return 'name' in obj;
}

function isAnimal(obj: any): obj is Animal {
    return 'species' in obj;
}

console.log(adaptor({ species: 'foo' })); // prints 'foo'
console.log(adaptor({ name: 'bar' })); // prints 'bar'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgoipUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwIF8DRIoBBVB8qQA2mHAWK1IAYwYRENOoxbsCBKWjpRSAE1JhgyeKIAU44kzABXYDThI0UAD69+goQBoCASgX0mzTAA+MUJzADNjBkQ7FFRI1CtgLy88UIkieAhgS3h0MCVgGLR4xK8AbjMiNigIIURoBgiovgFhEutk1PTiTOzcqHymYBa3dqSKtKhq2vqQ7qJgAAt4ZAB3KABReBX4YwAiAEkE6ygokmRgKGQwqC5oIvRDF1ahPfLKqfYJgjDLVClgAwHINUIUELExrZwWgvHMelkcugLNYAHRkSgqfA-P4AoF5AojNrImzPNywrrwvpI47AFGIaSyRCY7H-QEOKIPYzIABGACsaKRUCAfFc+adELBoegKRkEf0AOToiDy06PPkTDhY-C-Vl48WEoRcvkCoUinm88Wk4Rw2VUqDy+kQGRyFVMUW8jWqfDqVAoIQQFFCZDMYw6PQGXbYSROxk0eVhZDIFVsZITH1+gNBkNh-SGYxRpVx7mkeDJ1NAA)

Comment: ok I should have used a custom type instead of string/number as thats my use case. apologies, i will update example

Comment: @Omi For custom types it's slightly more inconvenient to stay type safe, ill update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You might check the type before calling the printString/Numberfunction:

```
    ...
    switch(type) {
       case 'greeting': {
          if (typeof(input) == 'string') return printString(input);
          break;
          }
       case 'age': {
          if (typeof(input) == 'number') return printNumber(input);
          break;
          }
```

You can also change your functions and overload them with both string and number:

```
   ...
    switch(type) {
       case 'greeting': 
          return printAny(input);
       case 'age': 
          return printAny(input);
   }
   ...
   function printAny(input: string) {
      return "Hello" + input
   }

   function printNumber(input: number) {
      return  input + 100
   }
```